# PHP, Remove a string inside double quotation mark using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a PHP string of the following format:

```
$str = 'This is a "sample string"';
```

I want to remove the double quoted string.  Like this:

```
This is a
```

What I tried:

```
$fileread = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s',' -', $fileread);
$fileread = preg_replace('![ \t]*//.*[ \t]*[\r\n]!', '', $fileread);
$separator = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/','',$fileread);
$separator = explode(" ",$separator);
```

Is there an easier way to extract that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply match a string contained inside a double quotes and replace it with an empty string:

```
$str = 'This is a "sample string".';

$str = preg_replace('/".*"/', '', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: This is what I'm searching for. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $str = 'This is a "sample string".';
    $str = preg_replace('#(").*?(")#', '', $str);
    echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

> $fileread = preg_replace('("+[a-z A-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*()]+")', "",
>   $fileread);

Answer (score 0):

To ensure fastest processing by the regex engine, use a greedy quantifier (`*`) with a negated character class `[^"]`).

I'll even remove an optional leading space to make the output cleaner.  If the quote string(s) might be the first or last word, then you'll need to use two branches -- one with an optional leading space and one with an optional trailing space.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sgplW))

```
$str = 'This is a "sample string" more text';

var_export(
    preg_replace('~ ?"[^"]*"~', '', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
'This is a more text'
```